# Are there general guidelines to make a grammar unambiguous?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I realized that we can't have more than one uppercase letter of the same type.

For instance, we can have S -> AB, but not S -> BB.

Is there any other principles we must abide to when writing an unambiguous grammar?

Comment: I don't think even the rule you stated is always true.  For example if one has $S\to BB; B\to b$ the grammar is unambiguous.